# How to make a dynamic list with audio data from json?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using an assets_audio_player and I faced to some problem when i tryed to use sources from json.
I have two screens with my player. First screen is just list with onPressed items, Second screen is a carousel player. When i want to open a Second screen - i want to get a current playlist possition with ability to go back and ahead but my player doesn't work correct.

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  currentSongs = widget.data['index'];
  allSongs = widget.data['songs'];
  audioList = loadAudioList();
  setupPlaylist();
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  audioPlayer.stop();
  super.dispose();
}

loadAudioList() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allSongs.length; i++) {
    audio = allSongs[i]['fields']['audio'][0]['url'].toString();
    title = allSongs[i]['fields']['name'].toString();
    subtitle = allSongs[i]['fields']['type'].toString();
    image = allSongs[i]['fields']['cover'][0]['url'].toString();
    audioList.add(
      Audio.network(audio,
          metas: Metas(
              title: title, artist: subtitle, image: MetasImage.file(image))),
    );
  }
  return audioList;
}

void setupPlaylist() async {
  var list = audioList.length;
  print(list);
  audioPlayer.open(Playlist(audios: audioList, startIndex: currentSongs),
      autoStart: false, showNotification: true, loopMode: LoopMode.none);
}
```

If i store a static list in List - is okay. but i want to store a dynamic list of music from API. Help me, please.

Comment: try compare you list data from api and your static list data, it must has different. fix it to make same data as static